# networkx pagerank on undirected graph?

Tags: python, networkx

I notice that you can apply pagerank to an undirected graph in networkx Graph() as well as DiGraph(). What does it mean though? Does it simply treat each edge in an undirected graph as bi-directional?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank.html?highlight=pagerank):

> Undirected graphs will be converted to a directed
>         graph with two directed edges for each undirected edge.